# Rerun C# failed tests with xUnit framework in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, xunit

I'm wondering if anyone has a way of rerunning failed tests automatically on Team City? I'm using C#, XUNIT and Selenium for a suite of automated UI tests. They can be flakey and a simple rerun will pass the test on the second try. I can't seem to find a solution. I've used other frameworks before that allow you to pass a console param for reruns.

Answer (score 0):

This is something you have to do at the level of your test runner, i.e. xUnit. You can consider [xUnitRetry](https://github.com/giggio/xunit-retry) plugin (the link has installation documentation):

```
[Retry(5)] //will try 5 times
public void TryAFewTimes()
{
    tried++;
    Assert.True(tried >= 5);
}
```